# Why python do not support element insertion in set?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to understand, What is the internal design strategy so that, it can not allow element insertion in set.
Following link describe that set is implemented using dictionary,where every element of set is a key.

**https://docs.python.org**

So,why is it not supporting similar operation like update in dictionary.

Comment: You *can* add elements to sets.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, look:

```
>>> a=set()
>>> a.add(1)
>>> a
{1}
>>> a.update([2,3,4,5])
>>> a
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot at this...Sets are *implemented* using dictionaries, but the function is a bit different. However, what do you mean by "can not allow element insertion"? You can insert elements using .update() and .add() (see the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Unless you are referring to immutable sets (i.e. frozenset), in which case that is an entirely different function whose goal is to be, well, immutable, so it doesn't allow updating values.